# How to stretch the background color of a child element so that it has the same height as the parent element while using float?

Tags: css

Please help a Java guy with a simple CSS problem. Been trying for hours and can't find a proper solution to the problem: How to stretch the background color of a child element so that it has the same height as the parent element while using float? I bet it has something to do with `display:flex`, but I can't get it to work :-/

Here's the code: https://jsfiddle.net/bycor29w/

**Goal:** Right column background colour must be filled to the same height as the middle column no matter how much or little text it contains

**Requirement:** Must use float

StackOverflow demands: "Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code", so here you go:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<style>
    div {
        border: 1px #000 solid;
    }

    .container {
        height: 100%;
        width:980px;
        float:left;
        display: flex;
    }

    .left {
        width: 200px;
        float: left;
    }

    .mid{
        padding-top: 1px;
        width: 560px;
        float: left;
    }

    .right {
        background: #d8d8d8 repeat-y bottom right;
        padding: 0 20px;
        height:100%;
        align-self: center;
        flex: 1;
        width: 180px;
        float: left;
    }
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
        asdf<br>
        asdf<br>
        asdf<br>
    </div>
    <div class="mid">
        asdf<br>
        asdf<br>
        asdf<br>
        asdf<br>
        asdf<br>
        asdf<br>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        asdf
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why you must use float?

Comment: Because it's homework for a friend who wanted to use an image, but I said: "No, that's crap, you can do anything with CSS nowadays", while having no idea about CSS :D

Comment: `:)` maybe something like this https://jsfiddle.net/bycor29w/2/.

Comment: Instead of floating for my projects, I've just made the `div` have an `inline-block` display, then limit the width to either a fixed amount, or a percentage of the screen. It worked beautifully for a side bar.

Comment: Damn it. I guess that's the proper way, but it must use float. But thanks anyway for the code!

Comment: The problem with the 100% height is that you need to set a height on all parent elements (container, body, html in this case). This will work but of course your height is no longer dictated by the middle column text

Comment: Flexbox will override floats...if you want to use floats...don't use flexbox.

Comment: You should post picture of what you are trying to achieve, but here are some other examples https://jsfiddle.net/bycor29w/6/, https://jsfiddle.net/bycor29w/7/, also using float to get same height columns, i am not sure about that...

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, Flexbox will override floats...if you want to use floats...don't use flexbox.

What you seem to want can be achieved using CSS tables....you can still use floats if absolutely necessary.

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div {
  border: 1px #000 solid;
}
.container {
  width: 580px;
  display: table;
  overflow: auto;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.left {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.mid {
  padding-top: 1px;
  width: 370px;
  float: left;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.right {
  background: lightblue;
  width: 100px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left">
      asdf
      <br>asdf
      <br>asdf
      <br>
    </div>
    <div class="mid">
      asdf
      <br>asdf
      <br>asdf
      <br>asdf
      <br>asdf
      <br>asdf
      <br>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      asdf
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually also came to the same solution using display:table, but the problem is that float:left is then useless. You can delete it and it still works. I start slowly to believe think using an image is the proper way if float is mandatory :-/